# How to check equality of collection type properties, using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, comparison

I have a class with many properties, some of them are lists of custom types.
I need to compare two instances of this class, and get a list of properties that aren't equal in them.

I designed it with custom attributes (for the relevant properties that I want to include in the comparison), and using the `IEquatable`, but for the lists I ran into problems. I was going to use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567.aspx) but it requires the type of the list (`IEnumerable<SomeType>`), which I don't have and don't know how to set. I'm aware of the [`GetElementType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getelementtype.aspx) and [`GetGenericArguments`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) methods but I can't use them inside `IEnumerable<>` to make the `SequenceEqual` work.

I'm looking for the best design for this scenario, and also code examples of how to actually do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318210/compare-equality-between-two-objects-in-nunit

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411232/comparing-two-objects

Comment: This question depends on lots of details in your code.  Could you supply that code so we can see the details we need in order to help you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798117/comparing-2-custom-objects-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/375996/compare-the-content-of-two-objects-for-equality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Codeplex project performs a deep compare of any two .NET objects using reflection:
http://comparenetobjects.codeplex.com/

#### Project Description

Perform a deep compare of any two .NET objects using reflection. Shows the differences between the two objects.

#### Compatiblity

Compatible with .NET Framework 3.5 and higher. New in 2.0, portable Class Library version works with .NET 4.0+, Silverlight 5+, Windows Phone 8+, Windows RT 8+, Xamarin iOS, and Xamarin Droid

#### NuGet Package

http://www.nuget.org/packages/CompareNETObjects